# Gathering data-* information with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using JQuery slider and trying to pass data to it using the HTML5 `data-` method, but its failing:

HTML:

```
<div class="editSlider" data-min="-20" data-max="20" data-editValue="curValB"></div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".editSlider").slider({                   
    value: 0,
    min: $(this).data("min"),
    max: $(this).data("max"),
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("editValue") = ui.value;
        $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').text(Math.round(curValB));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("editValue") = ui.value;
        this.doSomething();             
    }
});
```

I get this error in inspector:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
$(this).data("editValue") = ui.value;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) incorrectly to set `data-editValue`.

Simply change this:

```
$(this).data("editValue") = ui.value;
```

to this:

```
$(this).data("editValue", ui.value);
```

When getting use `$(selector).data('key');` and when setting use `$(selector).data('key', 'value');`

Answer (score 0):

`.data()` *setter*

```
$(this).data("editValue",ui.value);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/data/